# how to change keys of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

I have the following array of objects.  How do I change the keys of the array (0,1) to the skipperid (217,1)

```
[0:
        {
            "type": "RES",
            "date": "2022-05-14",
            "doy": 133,
            "skipperid": 217,
            "boat": "Laura",
            "start": "09:00:00",
            "end": "22:00:00",
            "spots": 5,
            "fname": "David",
            "lname": "Cross"
        }, 
     1:{
            "type": "SAIL",
            "date": "2022-05-14",
            "doy": 133,
            "skipperid": 1,
            "boat": "Avrora",
            "start": "10:00:00",
            "end": "13:00:00",
            "spots": 3,
            "fname": "Bob",
            "lname": "Smith"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: array keys are indexes, are you saying you want to move the item at index `0` to index `217`?

Comment: If you want to use the skipperid as the key, you'd need to copy everything into an Object.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript arrays always have numeric indexes. If you want to have keys, you'll need to convert into an object as shown here.

```js
let data = [{
    "type": "RES",
    "date": "2022-05-14",
    "doy": 133,
    "skipperid": 217,
    "boat": "Laura",
    "start": "09:00:00",
    "end": "22:00:00",
    "spots": 5,
    "fname": "David",
    "lname": "Cross"
  },
  {
    "type": "SAIL",
    "date": "2022-05-14",
    "doy": 133,
    "skipperid": 1,
    "boat": "Avrora",
    "start": "10:00:00",
    "end": "13:00:00",
    "spots": 3,
    "fname": "Bob",
    "lname": "Smith"
  }
]

data = data.reduce((b,a) => ({...b, [a.skipperid]:a}), {});
console.log(data['217'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I definitely suggest using an object like @Kinglish example.

Moving the position from current index to index by skipperid creates an array of size (*highest skipperid*), leaving all `index != skipperid` as `undefined`

***USE AN OBJECT***

**This is messy**:

```js
let data = [{
    "type": "RES",
    "date": "2022-05-14",
    "doy": 133,
    "skipperid": 217,
    "boat": "Laura",
    "start": "09:00:00",
    "end": "22:00:00",
    "spots": 5,
    "fname": "David",
    "lname": "Cross"
  },
  {
    "type": "SAIL",
    "date": "2022-05-14",
    "doy": 133,
    "skipperid": 1,
    "boat": "Avrora",
    "start": "10:00:00",
    "end": "13:00:00",
    "spots": 3,
    "fname": "Bob",
    "lname": "Smith"
  }
]
data.forEach((o,i,self)=> {
if(o?.skipperid != i){
self[o.skipperid] = o;
self[i] = undefined
}
})
console.log(data)
```

Comment: I don’t think you are correct. Keys are just strings. Having a key of 0 and another key of 217 does not create an object of 218 keys where 216 are undefined

Comment: it doesn't create an object, it creates an array. For example, if you run `array=[]; array[217]="Something"; console.log(array);` you will get an array of 218 indexes where 216 are undefined and index 217 being `'Something'`

Answer (score 0):

**Observations :**

- `JSON` you provided is not a valid `JSON`.
- result will be an `object` instead of an `array`.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const arr = [{
        "type": "RES",
        "date": "2022-05-14",
        "doy": 133,
        "skipperid": 217,
        "boat": "Laura",
        "start": "09:00:00",
        "end": "22:00:00",
        "spots": 5,
        "fname": "David",
        "lname": "Cross"
    },
    {
        "type": "SAIL",
        "date": "2022-05-14",
        "doy": 133,
        "skipperid": 1,
        "boat": "Avrora",
        "start": "10:00:00",
        "end": "13:00:00",
        "spots": 3,
        "fname": "Bob",
        "lname": "Smith"
    }
];

const obj = {};

arr.forEach((item) => {
    obj[item.skipperid] = item
});

console.log(obj)
```